# why overriding attribute works only on some models?

Tags: octobercms

I have created two models - main model which can have many names:

```
Units:
id|unit desc

and
UnitNames:
id|unit_id|name
```

In controller/units/config_relation.yaml I defined fragment, which show all names related to unit:

```
names:
  label: Names
  view:
    list: $/xxx/yyy/models/unitname/columns.yaml
    toolbarButtons: create
    showSorting: false
    defaultSort:
      column: valid_from
      direction: desc
  manage:
    form: $/xxx/yyy/models/unitname/fields.yaml
```

Everything works perfectly.
But. I need to add virtual fields -

```
public function getStupidAttribute() {
      return 'it is stupid';
    }
```

And in models/UnitNames.php it works. But in models/Unit.php - It doesn't. It even doesn't enter this function (I puted die() inside)

Why not and how to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Damn it!! SORTING!!! The error drives to wrong path!

Just have to add `sortable:false` to `columns.yaml` (BTW it makes other complication to me...)